# Android component that displays the thumbnail of its children before loading data

Tags: android

I am making a native android application and I would like to know if there is a particular component which allows to manage the display of the screen before and after loading the data as on the attached images.

[Before loading data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK19N.jpg)

[After loading data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoXqG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear and specific, so I'll try to answer it more generally.

If you want to create a circular loading progress bar as the one shown in your screenshots you can either create/use a custom loader or you can try using something like [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar).

If you want to create a layout as the one shown and you are reffering to the image loading for what appear to be video thumbnails, then you can use an image loading library such as [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

If you want to download some resources and you are referring to the networking aspect of this process you can use a networking library such as [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley).

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear. I want to know if there is an android component that automatically manages the display kind of its children as a thumbnail as shown in the first image

Comment: @AristideEtoumi I believe that there's not such a thing officially in Android. So, you can either create this layout from scratch using a RecyclerView or if you're lucky maybe you can find a similar custom implementation in an open source project in github.